# Getting promise error in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Server js:

```
var user_controller = require('./controllers/user_controller');
passport.use(new passportLocal(function(username, password, done) {
  user_controller.login(username, password).then(function(value) {
    if (value) {
      console.log(value + "true")

      done(null, {
        id: username,
        name: username
      });
    } else {
      console.log(value + "false");
      done(null, null);
    }
  })
}));
```

USer contoller:

```
module.exports.login = function(username, password) {
  var status;
  var userid = username;
  User.findOne({
    'username': [userid],
    'password': [password]
  }, function(err, user) {
    if (!user) {
      console.log("logged err");
      status = false;
    } else {
      console.log("login in");
      status = true;
    }
    console.log(status);
    return status;
  });
};
```

I am doing an async task (db call) in my user_controller.login and it returns a boolean "value"

But when I execute this I am getting error:Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

I saw previous questions on this error but couldnt understand it

Comment: Can you share the code of user_controller.js ?

Comment: You don't return anything from your `login` function, so the result of that call is `undefined`  and because of that you try to call `.then`  on `undefined`. You need to change your code in a way that `login` returns a Promise.

Comment: But I am returning var status from login function return status; is given code in user controller @t.niese

Comment: `function(err, user) {`  is called async, the `return` is for that callback and not for the `login`.

Comment: Sorry so how do I return status for the login function,I tried to return it before but it was happening asynchronously @t.niese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try with callback function. The login function takes one callback param and execute that function at end.

```
module.exports.login = function(username, password, callback) {
  var status;
  var userid = username;
  User.findOne({
    'username': [userid],
    'password': [password]
  }, function(err, user) {
    if (!user) {
      console.log("logged err");
      status = false;
    } else {
      console.log("login in");
      status = true;
    }
    console.log(status);
    callback(status);
  });
};
```

While calling the function login pass the third param as a callback function.

```
var user_controller = require('./controllers/user_controller');
passport.use(new passportLocal(function(username, password, done) {
  user_controller.login(username, password, function(value) {
    if (value) {
      console.log(value + "true")

      done(null, {
        id: username,
        name: username
      });
    } else {
      console.log(value + "false");
      done(null, null);
    }
  })
}));
```

Note: I am not tested the above code.

Comment: You !!!! solved my problem for what i was researching about for hrs ,ill remember use callback instead of promises thanks million bro

Answer (score 0):

You can create promise based functions in Nodejs using [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) library.

```
npm install q
```

Below code can help you.

```
module.exports.login=function(username,password){
var status;
var userid=username;

User.findOne({'username':[userid], 'password':[password]},function(err,user){
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    if(err){
       deferred.reject(err); 
    } else{
        deferred.resolve(data);
    }
    return deferred.promise;
});
```

and use it in Server.js

```
var user_controller = require('./controllers/user_controller');
passport.use(new passportLocal(function(username, password, done) {
user_controller.login(username, password).then(function(user) {
  done(null, {
    id: username,
    name: username
  });
});
```